# How can I make setEnabled work on a customised UISegmentedControl in iOS5?

Tags: ios5, customization, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl in my iPad app which I have customised with the new methods available in iOS5, as below:

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentUnselectedUnselected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentSelectedUnselected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segUnselectedSelected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17], UITextAttributeFont,
                                [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.34 blue:0.42 alpha:1], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                CGSizeMake(0, 1), UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It looks fine and works ok, but there's a problem in that calling setEnabled:NO on any of the segments has no effect - the segment will still respond to touch events.  Does anybody know what I need to do to disable some of the segments?

Comment: If you comment out all of your appearance code, does enabling/disabling work like you expect?

Comment: Yes, it works fine without the customisation. I'm guessing there must be something else I need to add to get it to work.  Slightly off-topic but setting a segment width doesn't work with the appearance code applied either

Comment: i'm just running into customized uisegmented control acting weird with setEnabled:forSegmentAtIndex:. any solution? i might have to add custom overlay for the disabled state...

Comment: I never did solve it I'm afraid.  I spent a few hours trying to get it to work, but in the end I had to resort to recreating it with UIButtons

Answer (score 0):

Use `isEnabledForSegmentAtIndex:` and `setEnabled:forSegmentAtIndex:` found in the [documentation for UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html). Let me know if that gets it working.

Comment: For the code '[self.segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
        BOOL isEnabled = [self.segmentedControl isEnabledForSegmentAtIndex:0];' isEnabled is set to NO, yet the control still fires its valueChanged action method when segment 0 is tapped

Comment: I just realized you don't have an image set for UIControlStateDisabled. I don't know if this is the cause of the problem, but it may be useful to have that.

Comment: Good point. I tried setting images for all the options implementing UIControlStateDisabled but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an issue for anyone (since it's fixed in iOS 6, but here's the workaround that worked from me (borrowed from another question):

In your viewDidLoad, try:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    [self.segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:2];
});
```

It seems that when the views load, the presence of an appearance proxy resets the other properties of the UISegmentedControl.  Scheduling this on the main thread will re-enable/re-disable.  This also BTW works for selecting the default segment.